# Magento1 Get Item Details From Order Collection

Tags: magento-1.9, order-collection

in Magento 1.9 I am working on order collection I am getting order collection successfully using the below code now I want to get item details from order how I can get this.I am using this collection

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the order items using the below code snippet. Loop through each order and get the item details.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
$items = array();
foreach($orders as $order) {
    // Get Items from the order
    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem){
         $items[] = $orderItem->getData();

     }
}
```

Comment: i also want to skip if orders status follow one of them i want skip those orders

Comment: Add the status filter at the end of your order collection                                  $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))     
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => array('canceled','complete')));

Comment: Actually you can either use 'in' (In Filter) or 'nin' (Not In Filter) to skip or fetch the orders you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetching order collection and item details by the following code

```
$ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
        ->load();

        count($ordercollection);

foreach ($ordercollection as $orderkey => $ordervalue) { 
    foreach ($ordervalue->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $sku = $item->getSku();
        $name = $item->getName();
        $qty = $item->getOrderedQty();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
   $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
```

Getting order item ids:

```
$orderedItems = $orders->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderedProductIds = [];
foreach ($orderedItems as $item) {
    $orderedProductIds[] = $item->getData('product_id');
}
```

Getting products:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addIdFilter($orderedProductIds)
```